# Extracting data from a text file to use in a python script?

Tags: python, regex

Basically, I have a file like this:

```
Url/Host:   www.example.com
Login:     user
Password:   password
Data_I_Dont_Need:    something_else
```

How can I use RegEx to separate the details to place them into variables?

Sorry if this is a terrible question, I can just never grasp RegEx. So another question would be, can you provide the RegEx, but kind of explain what each part of it is for?

Comment: Using str.split(":") is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the entries in a dictionary, not in so many separate variables -- clearly, the keys you're using need *NOT* be acceptable as variable names (that slash in 'Url/Host' would be a killer!-), but they'll be just fine as string keys into a dictionary.

```
import re

there = re.compile(r'''(?x)      # verbose flag: allows comments & whitespace
                       ^         # anchor to the start
                       ([^:]+)   # group with 1+ non-colons, the key
                       :\s*      # colon, then arbitrary whitespace
                       (.*)      # group everything that follows
                       $         # anchor to the end
                    ''')
```

and then

```
 configdict = {}
 for aline in open('thefile.txt'):
   mo = there.match(aline)
   if not mo:
     print("Skipping invalid line %r" % aline)
     continue
   k, v = mo.groups()
   configdict[k] = v
```

the possibility of making RE patterns "verbose" (by starting them with `(?x)` or using `re.VERBOSE` as the second argument to `re.compile`) is very useful to allow you to clarify your REs with comments and nicely-aligning whitespace.  I think it's sadly underused;-).

Comment: Nice answer and great explanation. I think I'd like potential whitespace on the value removed. I believe that could be done by adding \s* between the value group and the end-of-line anchor '$'?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @Rob, you mean `groups`, not `group`.  Yes, I forgot to add the `continue` obviously needed to **do** the skip, let me add it.  BTW, your question doesn't mention that there can be lines that don't match this pattern, and what to do when such lines are found -- please edit your Q to add this crucial information!

Comment: @extraneon, if you want to remove trailing whitespace on the value, change the end of the RE's pattern to `(.*?)\s*$`.  The `?` here is crucial as it tells the RE to do the star-match non-greedily: without it, it would still match the trailing whitespace as part of this group!

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it matted. Edited it

Answer (score 1):

For a file as simple as this you don't really need regular expressions. String functions are probably easier to understand. This code:

```
def parse(data):
    parsed = {}    
    for line in data.split('\n'):
        if not line: continue # Blank line
        pair = line.split(':')
        parsed[pair[0].strip()] = pair[1].strip()
    return parsed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = """Url/Host:   www.example.com
    Login:     user
    Password:   password
"""
    print parse(test)
```

Will do the job, and results in:

```
{'Login': 'user', 'Password': 'password', 'Url/Host': 'www.example.com'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't know about regex, simply change you file like this:

```
Host = www.example.com
Login = uer
Password = password
```

And use ConfigParser python module http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

Comment: ConfigParser supports `:` delimiter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845018/extracting-data-from-a-text-file-to-use-in-a-python-script/2845923#2845923

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Better Solution**

```
for line in input: 
    key, val = re.search('(.*?):\s*(.*)', line).groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

[ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser) module supports `':'` delimiter.

```
import ConfigParser
from cStringIO import StringIO

class Parser(ConfigParser.RawConfigParser):
    def _read(self, fp, fpname):
        data = StringIO("[data]\n"+fp.read()) 
        return ConfigParser.RawConfigParser._read(self, data, fpname)

p = Parser()
p.read("file.txt")
print dict(p.items("data"))
```

Output:

```
{'login': 'user', 'password': 'password', 'url/host': 'www.example.com'}
```

Though a regex or manual parsing might be more appropriate in your case.